# R: Smart way to replace column/vector values by multiple rules?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have raw values that I need to recode into 0-1 following few thresholds and calculation. This is how formula looks like:
[image]

I think this simply says:

- if x < 60 ->  x = 0
- if x > 60 & <= 80 -> x = 0.05*x -3
- if x > 80 -> x  = 1

And here is my approach:

```
# V is from 0-600 m3/ha
set.seed(3)
V_pine = sample.int(100, 10)  # generate 10 random numbers up to 100

> V_pine
[1]  5 58 12 36 99 95  8 20 74 55

# Recode values following multiple ifelse statements
for (i in V_pine){
  if (i <= 60) {
    i <- 0
    } else if (i > 60 & i<= 80) {
      i <- (0.05* i )-3
    } else if (i > 80) {
      i<- 1
    }
  print(i)
}
```

Seems that this brings correct results:

```
Output: 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0.7 0
```

Yet, as I have another many similar functions/formulas, I wonder if **there is another way how to simplify `for loop` and `ifelse` statements?**

My data will be stored in `data.frame` so use of `dplyr` and `mutate` would be great. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Using your data as data.frame
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(V_pine = sample.int(100, 10))

df %>% 
  mutate(
    recode = case_when(
      V_pine < 60 ~ 0, 
      V_pine > 60 & V_pine <= 80  ~ 0.05*V_pine-3, 
      V_pine > 80  ~ 1, 
    ))
```

Output:

```
     V_pine recode
1      17      0
2      80      1
3      38      0
4      32      0
5      58      0
6      96      1
7      12      0
8      28      0
9      54      0
10     95      1
```

Comment: You solution looks nice. I don't think you used the correct seed.

Comment: I used the same seed, thought I don't know why it gave me different numbers. Maybe because he used `samle.int` to create a vector and I a data frame?

Comment: I get the OP's V_pine values when I run your code. Maybe run this again and see.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R

```
df$recode <- ifelse(df$V_pine <= 60, 0, ifelse(df$V_pine > 80, 1, df$V_pine*0.05 - 3))
df
```

> ```
>    V_pine recode
> 1       5    0.0
> 2      58    0.0
> 3      12    0.0
> 4      36    0.0
> 5      99    1.0
> 6      95    1.0
> 7       8    0.0
> 8      20    0.0
> 9      74    0.7
> 10     55    0.0
> ```